# How can I turn off the system alert noise in Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: noise

Long story short I'm tired of hearing this dog bark every time I use tab complete. But when I check my settings the option to turn this alert off no longer exists.  I only see options to change the sound type to some other annoying noise.

Comment: You have the option to set the volume to zero.

Comment: But does that system volume only cover the alert sound?  Am I missing any other sounds because of it?

Comment: The system sounds have a distinct volume control, independent of the system wide volume control or individual programs' volume. It's that simple.

Comment: I'm asking if there are other system sounds I'd be missing besides the annoying bark / chirp that I might want?  I just want to turn off this one particular system sound, not necessarily all system sounds.  

I understand this doesn't effect all sounds generally.

Comment: FedKad's answer is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `dconf-editor`, go to **/ org / gnome / terminal / legacy / profiles**, find the *profile id* that is relevant to you, and set **audible-bell** to **false**.

You can find the *profile id* of your relevant "terminal profile" by going to **Preferences** (at `gnome-terminal`), selecting the "relevant profile", and looking at the bottom right of the dialog box.

Note that, this way, you will lose *any audible feedback* from the terminal for that terminal profile. (You can test with `echo -e '\a'`.)